# Disable HTML karate test reporting

Tags: karate, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a karate test-suite that fail for GC overhead when generating the HTML report on a system with limited resources.

The report is not required, so I would like to disable the generation, but so far I didn't find how to do it.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you talking about the JUnit HTML report ? You can't. You can try to switch to the parallel runner for this test: https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution

Answer (score 1):

i see your pain mate. Have you gone far about this topic? i have tried everything mentioned on the issues and i think it's about a bug in karate framework which mentioned here https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1199

Btw, this error occurs when the tests are too much(couldn't specified the exact number). For example i have a test package with 203 scenarios , that one works fine but the other package has  376 scenarios and that one is getting this error.

I closed all the logs and minimized the dependencies in pom.xml and monitored the memory usage of the tests. Cpu usage around 350% while running just 1 scenario

Comment: can you do us a favor and test 0.9.9.RC2 and you can even disable reports: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide - also see https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1282

Comment: great works Peter! seems to be solved but now i reproduce the issue you commented. hopefully it will be resolved soon too.

Man thanks again. you are saving lives

Comment: great. can you be clear about what exactly is still an issue, you can comment on the issue if you want